# How to display data from selected option in django

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

I have a Django project that display data for Baseball players. I added a Select option on each html page. I would like to display individual player information based on the selection from dropdown.

Ex:
If i select "John Doe" from drop down, i would like to see only "John Doe's" information. How can i code this.

Here is my original views code:

HTML

```
<select class="player-dropdown">
<option value="pitcher">Joel Rodriguez</option>
<option value="pitcher">Yadiel Lugo</option>
<option value="pitcher">Cody Reeds</option>
<option value="pitcher">Xavier Colon</option>
<option value="pitcher">Andy Smith</option>
<option value="pitcher">Carson Rex</option>
<option value="pitcher">Jalen Jackson</option>
<option value="pitcher">Matthew Cobbs</option>
<option value="pitcher">Matt Sampson</option>
<option value="pitcher">John Harrison</option>
<option value="pitcher">Robert Santiago</option>
<option value="pitcher">Efrain Zuniga</option>
```

Views.py

```
def pitching(request):
results = Pitching.objects.all()
return render(request, 'pitchingdata.html', {'pitching': results})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a view about player's detail like this:

```
from .models import BaseballPlayer
from django.http.response import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render


def baseball_player_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        player = BaseballPlayer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except BaseballPlayer.DoesNotExists:
        raise Http404
    ..
    # handle with the player's information you want to display here 
    # (from model instance `player`)
    ..
    context = {
        'instance': player,
        ..
    }
    return render(request, 'baseball_player_detail.html' context),
```

And then you use `<a>` or anything you like to make user be able to visit this view.

Comment: how would you start the handle for the player's information?

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can use ajax, I have written a simple example which may help you.

# player-dropdown is the class name of the select option tag in html, on which the change event will occur and that will call a url through ajax and display data in the 'details' class name div.

# you also need to write an api or function which return data in json format for which the url can be '/ajax/search-detail/'


# html section

<select class="player-dropdown">
    <option>John Doe</option>
    <option>Roy</option>
</select>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="details">
    </tbody>
</table>


# javascript section

    $('.player-dropdown').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        selected_player_id = $('.player-dropdown').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: '/ajax/search-detail/' + selected_player_id,
        dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.details').empty();
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $(".details").append("\
                    <tr>\
                    <td>"+val['first_name']+"</td>\
                    <td>"+val['last_name']+"</td>\
                    <td>"+val['age']+"</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    ");
                });
            }
        });
    });



# python section


def search_vendor(request, pk):
    data_array = []

    try:
        player = BaseballPlayer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except BaseballPlayer.DoesNotExists:
        player = None

    if player:
        data_array.append({
        'fist_name': vendor.id,
        'last_name': vendor.vendor_company_name,
        'age': vendor.email
        })

    return JsonResponse(data_array, safe=False)
```

Comment: I tried this, but i get an error saying "type object has no attribute 'DoesNotExists'. If i erase that line, i get an error saying "pitching() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'.....pitching is the name of my view. Not sure what im missing. I'll update my question and add my orginal code.